# ExpandableListView Mono for Android, ClickEvents

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

How can i implement the click events on a expandable list view on monodroid, im trying doing like this code but it seems doenst work...Also, theres is not a IOGroupClickListener method.

```
listview.SetOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.IOnChildClickListener()
        {
            public override bool OnChildClick (ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
            {
                return base.OnChildClick (parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# doesn't support anonymous subclasses like Java, you will need to create a proper class that implements IOnChildClickListener:

```
public class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, ExpandableListView.IOnChildClickListener
{
    public override bool OnChildClick (ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
    {
        return base.OnChildClick (parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
    }
}
```

Or, depending on what you are trying to do, you may be better off using one of the events, like:

- ExpandableListView.GroupCollapse
- ExpandableListView.GroupExpand
- AdapterView.ItemClick
- AdapterView.ItemSelected

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the missinge code, which i felt should be there in selected answer

```
public class MyListener : Java.Lang.Object, ExpandableListView.IOnChildClickListener
{
    public override bool OnChildClick (ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
    {
        return base.OnChildClick (parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id);
    }
}
```

In OnCreateView add this specified listener to the the list view using below code

```
listview.SetOnChildClickListener(new MyListener());
```

This adds the above created class as a listener and receive callbacks.